# Android - Controlling a task with Timer and TimerTask?

Tags: android, timer, scheduled-tasks

I am currently trying to set up a WiFi Scan in my Android application that scans for WiFi access points every 30 seconds.

I have used Timer and TimerTask to get the scan running correctly at the intervals which I require.

However I want to be able to stop and start the scanning when the user presses a button and I am currently having trouble stopping and then restarting the Timer and TimerTask.

Here is my code

```
TimerTask scanTask;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer t = new Timer();

public void doWifiScan(){

scanTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                         wifiManager.scan(context); 
                         Log.d("TIMER", "Timer set off");
                        }
               });
        }};


    t.schedule(scanTask, 300, 30000); 

 }

  public void stopScan(){

   if(scanTask!=null){
      Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
      scanTask.cancel();
 }

}
```

So the Timer and Task start fine and the scan happens every 30 seconds however I cant get it to stop, I can stop the Timer but the task still occurs and scanTask.cancel() doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I missing something in the Timer/TimerTask classes?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might consider:

- Examining the boolean result from calling `cancel()` on your task, as it should indicate if your request succeeds or fails
- Try `purge()` or `cancel()` on the `Timer` instead of the `TimerTask`

If you do not necessarily need `Timer` and `TimerTask`, you can always use `postDelayed()` (available on Handler and on any `View`). This will schedule a `Runnable` to be executed on the UI thread after a delay. To have it recur, simply have it schedule itself again after doing your periodic bit of work. You can then monitor a boolean flag to indicate when this process should end. For example:

```
private Runnable onEverySecond=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do real work here

        if (!isPaused) {
            someLikelyWidget.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried to check the boolean on the scanTask like this       

boolean tf = scanTask.cancel();          

But I now get a Null Pointer Exception on that line.    


However the task itself is running fine??     

I will eventually be running the code in a Service so would using postDelayed be an option?

Comment: Obviously, `scanTask` is being reset to `null`, and from the code fragments you have presented it is impossible to say why or nhow. `postDelayed()` is not an option in a `Service`, but it is unclear why you want/need a `Service` in this case.

Comment: scanTask is not used anywhere else in the code of the entire application, nor is Timer, what I've posted is the entire use of the Timer t and the TimerTask scanTask.  I want to create an application with minimal to no UI so from reading about Android a service is the way to do this?

Comment: Same problem for me and I have tried the cancel and purge for the timer.  If I exit the page (back or home), I cancel in onPause and onStop.  The thread runs for its remaining time -- i cannot cancel the timer or interrupt the thread?!  This is not behaving as documented unless my code (similar to this) is wrong.

Comment: as top stop timer, do I need to use both purge and cancel, or either purge or cancel?

Answer (score 6):

using your code, instead of

```
scanTask.cancel();
```

the correct way is to cancel your timer (not timerTask):

```
t.cancel();
```

Answer (score 5):

The Android documentation says that cancel() Cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks. If there is a currently running task it is not affected. No more tasks may be scheduled on this Timer. Subsequent calls do nothing. Which explains the issue.