# Timer and TimerTask in Android

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I need a timer for my program. I have written it and it works fine on PC in emulalator program (Android 1.5/2.2). But it doesn't work on the real device (Android 1.5). What am I doing wrong?

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (condition) {
                    myFunc();
                } else {
                    this.cancel();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 500, 85);
```

Comment: Go through this [android-controlling-a-task-with-timer-and-timertask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161750/android-controlling-a-task-with-timer-and-timertask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Controlling a task with Timer and TimerTask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161750/android-controlling-a-task-with-timer-and-timertask)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to cancel() timer not the timer task.