# Assistance Android Manifest Please

Tags: java, android

I need a hand with the Android Manifest file.
I have 4 java files called: MainActivity, Splash, TextPlay and Menu. I want the Splash file to be displayed first. (I have it set for 5 seconds)
I then want the Menu to be displayed(I have the rest of the files displayed on Menu page.)

The app also wont debug on the emulator and im guessing its the manifests fault.
Can someone help me achieve this, Thanks!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.intigerdev.numberapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.intigerdev.numberapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Nobody would like to look at your splash screen for N seconds. (true story) (N not necessary >= 5)

Comment: btw, splash screens are generally considered bad UX (user experience) design. consider reworking the launch of your app to avoid this.

Comment: In my opinion it looks more professional.

Comment: your opinion will change when you learn Android way of doing UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to move between activities on your own.  The manifest doesn't do that for you.. if you want your app to start on the Splash screen use this manifest instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.intigerdev.numberapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

`OnCreate` of the Splash activity ([stackoverflow.com/a/6489385/736496](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6489385/736496)):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, The emulator is running it now but the splash screen isnt closing after 5 seconds. Is this right:  protected void onCreate(Bundle BundleName) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(BundleName);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash);
  Thread timer = new Thread(){
   public void run(){
    try{
     sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
     Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.intigerdev.numberapp.MENU");
     startActivity(openMainActivity);
    }
   }
  };
  timer.start();
 }

}

Comment: did that fix your problem?

Comment: I got it working thanks, now i must just figure out how to make menu items clickable!